# xts format assign name for index column

Tags: r, xts

I have a xts file format which when reading didn't have a name for the index column, see below. How do I assign a name to it? Ideally, I wanted to use the date time field for plotting at subsequent stages. Thanks.

```
                    Elapsed Time Total Inflow Total Evap Surface Infil
2021-04-30 10:02:00        0.033            0      0.125             0
2021-04-30 10:04:00        0.067            0      0.125             0
2021-04-30 10:06:00        0.100            0      0.125             0
2021-04-30 10:08:00        0.133            0      0.125             0
2021-04-30 10:10:00        0.167            0      0.125             0
2021-04-30 10:12:00        0.200            0      0.125             0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume that the question is asking how to plot an xts object such as x in the Note at the end.

There are numerous plotting functions for zoo and xts objects (every xts object is also a zoo object) so it is unnecessary to convert it to a data frame (although in the last example below we show this.)   *All the facilities of each of these plotting systems are available* when using this. Also shown below is how to specify the x label in each case.

```
library(xts)  # this also pulls in zoo

# classic graphics
plot(as.zoo(x), xlab = "Time")

# lattice graphics
library(lattice)
xyplot(x, xlab = "Time")

## ggplot2 graphics
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(x) + xlab("Time")

# convert to data frame and then use matplot
d <- fortify.zoo(x)
matplot(d[[1]], d[-1], xlab = "Time")
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "                 Elapsed Time  Total Inflow  Total Evap  Surface Infil
    2021-04-30 10:02:00        0.033            0      0.125             0
    2021-04-30 10:04:00        0.067            0      0.125             0
    2021-04-30 10:06:00        0.100            0      0.125             0
    2021-04-30 10:08:00        0.133            0      0.125             0
    2021-04-30 10:10:00        0.167            0      0.125             0
    2021-04-30 10:12:00        0.200            0      0.125             0"

# split into lines, trim whitespace off ends, replace 2+ spaces w comma
L <- Lines |>
  textConnection() |>
  readLines() |>
  trimws() |>
  gsub(pattern = "  +", replacement = ",")

z <- read.csv.zoo(text = L, index = 0, tz = "", check.names = FALSE)
x <- as.xts(z)
```

Comment: and `library(rtsplot); rtsplot(x, xlab = "Time")`

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to use plotting functions that can deal with `xts` data. There are not many functions that can do that.

Other option is to just make index as a separate column in the dataframe instead of an `xts` object.

```
library(xts)
data <- data.frame(index = index(sample.xts), coredata(sample.xts))
data

#         index     Open     High      Low    Close
#1   2007-01-02 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
#2   2007-01-03 50.23050 50.42188 50.23050 50.39767
#3   2007-01-04 50.42096 50.42096 50.26414 50.33236
#4   2007-01-05 50.37347 50.37347 50.22103 50.33459
#5   2007-01-06 50.24433 50.24433 50.11121 50.18112
#6   2007-01-07 50.13211 50.21561 49.99185 49.99185
#...
#...
```

**data**

```
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object')
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer to retain the format in xts as of now. Good to know it can be converted.